# How do I create a DNN module which can be placed on the same page multiple times with different content in the settings?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dnn9

I am creating a module which will allow me to save HTML content in the settings section of the DNN module which will be stored on the Portal Settings.

How do I ensure my setting is unique only for the current container it is placed on? How can I get the ID of the current div the module is placed on?

Then I would be able to place the module in the exact same place. For example the Header and Footer section of the website.

So, if I can get ParentDivID and then append it at the end of the settings key.

For example: if (dictSettings.ContainsKey("GlobalHTML" + **ParentDivID**))

This is my current code for the DNN module Settings Codebehind

```
if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
{
    //Updated to use Portal Settings instead of per page per tab settings
    var dictSettings = m_PortalController.GetPortalSettings(PortalId);

    if (dictSettings.ContainsKey("GlobalHTML"))
    {
     txtGlobalHTML.Text = dictSettings["GlobalHTML"];
    }

}
```

Comment: I believe each instance of a module has a unique ID. That would be the first thing I would look for. Another thing you could do is have a radio selection for header, footer, ect and then set the settings based on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You normally store store module settings in the ModuleSettings table of the `ModuleController`.

```
var modules = new ModuleController();
modules.UpdateTabModuleSetting(TabModuleId, "SettingKey", "SettingValue");
```

But for HTML I would create a custom table that stores the HTML with a Primary Key and a  `TabModuleId` column.

Comment: This doesn't take multiple portals into consideration. Also the question was how to differentiate between two of the same module on the same page.

Comment: It does not have to. ModuleID's are always unique, even across portals.

Comment: Alright. Been a while since I've worked with DNN I just remembering running into settings issues across portals.

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out a way to add the same module to the page on a particular portal and have the content that is already saved in the settings to be linked with the use of an ID which I can set.

So if I want the same telephone number on multiple pages or footer content, then I can leave the HTML field in the settings section empty and just make the ID the same as the one I have initially configured with HTML content.

This is the code for when the module settings loads:

```
 if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
 {
  per tab settings
  var dictSettings = m_PortalController.GetPortalSettings(PortalId);

  if (Settings.Contains("GlobalIDHTML"))
  {
  txtIDGlobalHTML.Text = Settings["GlobalIDHTML"].ToString();
  LinkID = Settings["GlobalIDHTML"].ToString();
  }

  if (dictSettings.ContainsKey("GlobalHTML"+ LinkID))
  {
  txtGlobalHTML.Text = dictSettings["GlobalHTML"+ LinkID];                       
  }      
}
```

This is the code for Updating the settings:

```
 public override void UpdateSettings()
 {
  try
     {
      var modules = new ModuleController();
      modules.UpdateModuleSetting(ModuleId, "GlobalIDHTML", txtIDGlobalHTML.Text);
      modules.UpdateTabModuleSetting(TabModuleId, "GlobalIDHTML", txtIDGlobalHTML.Text);
      var globalstoragevalue = "GlobalHTML"+ txtIDGlobalHTML.Text;

      if (txtGlobalHTML.Text != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtGlobalHTML.Text))
      {
      PortalController.UpdatePortalSetting(PortalId, globalstoragevalue, txtGlobalHTML.Text);
      }
    }
    catch (Exception exc) //Module failed to load
    {
     Exceptions.ProcessModuleLoadException(this, exc);
    }
  }
```

My code when the page loads:

```
  try
  {
     if (Settings["GlobalIDHTML"] != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Settings["GlobalIDHTML"].ToString()))
    {
    GlobalLinkID = Settings["GlobalIDHTML"].ToString();
    }
    GlobalContent = TryGetPortalSetting("GlobalHTML"+ GlobalLinkID);

    if (GlobalContent != null)
   {
    GlobalPageContent = GlobalContent;
   }                  
  }
```

The module settings:

[image]

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would look at how the HTML module does this ...